# PDI a.k.a Kettle Client-Server Setup

Tags: client-server, pentaho, data-integration

I am trying to setup the Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle) into Client-server and i have been following the steps from here

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/A+guide+to+setting+up+PDI+in+a+Microsoft+client-server+style+environment

The Server side setting says that i have to make changes in the carte.bat file and i have done as the steps says. (Atleast i think so !!).
 I thenhave to run the Carte.bat file and check the server status on my web page.But the server, i.e, the carte.bat file doesn't start in the first place and hence the status web page is not loading.

I am using the following URL : localhost:8086/kettle/status

and the changes i made in the last line of carte.bat file are as below.
Please tell where i went wrong and what is to be done.

REM ***************
REM ** Run...    **
REM ***************

cd /D %CWD%
"%_PENTAHO_JAVA%" %OPT% -jar "%KETTLE_DIR%\launcher\pentaho-application-launcher-5.0.1-stable.jar" -main start /belownormal javaw %OPT% org.pentaho.di.www.Carte.localhost:8086%*

Comment: link you mention is coming wih page-not found error.

try this link http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Carte+Configuration

Comment: Thank You for the response and Sorry for the inconvenience caused. I have updated the link. Can u please check it now.

Comment: Not able to figure out the problem, you can check with the link which i suggested, their are two ways try it, might be it will work.

Comment: can you tell us what is the error message (or what is otherwise displayed) when you're running carte.bat ?

Comment: After making the changes to the Carte.bat file as mentioned in the link I gave in my question, I tried to start the server by running the carte.bat file. But the server doesn't seems to have started and hence no web page is loading over carte.bat file. Its not giving any error message, neither it displaying anything else. Can you please guide me with this ? Thank you.